# Freeze Gridview header

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I would like the header frozen at the top because i have over 9000 rows. I have tried "fixed" but that doesn't look the best. It was fixed in place on scroll but looked like it was floating in place.  What can i do to get the top frozen? I tried a css style but it wasn't freezing the header either. If i can get the header frozen the next step is to freeze the footer on screen also so new entries can be made without having to go to the bottom on 9000 rows.

```
<asp:GridView id="myGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CssClass="Grid"
    Overflow="auto"    
    AllowSorting="False" 
    CellPadding="4" 
    ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None"
    ShowFooter="True"
    DataKeyNames="RMANumber"  width="99%">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="LightGray" />
    <Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RMA Number"  HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label id="lblRMANumber" runat="server" ReadOnly="false" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.RMANumber") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox id="txtEditRMANumber" size="16" runat="server" ReadOnly="false" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.RMANumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox id="txtAddRMANumber" size="16" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Decon Form? Y/N" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label id="lblDeconForm" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.DeconForm") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox id="txtEditDeconForm" size="16" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.DeconForm") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox id="txtAddDeconForm" size="16" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label id="lblCustomer" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Customer") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox id="txtEditCustomer" size="16" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Customer") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox id="txtAddCustomer" size="16" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Problem / Solution Found" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label id="lblProblemSolutionFound" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ProblemSolutionFound") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox id="txtEditProblemSolutionFound" size="16" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ProblemSolutionFound") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox id="txtAddProblemSolutionFound" size="16" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button id="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandName="Add" AutoPostBack="False"  ></asp:Button>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" CancelText="Cancel" DeleteText="Delete" EditText="Edit" UpdateText="Update" HeaderText="Modify" 
        ShowDeleteButton="False" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
        ButtonType="Image" CancelImageUrl="Images/Cancel.png" EditImageUrl="Images/Edit.png" UpdateImageUrl="Images/Update.png" ControlStyle-Width="60" ControlStyle-Height="20"/>
 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ShowHeader="true" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/Delete.png" Width="60" Height="20" VerticalAlign="Center"
                            CommandName="Delete"
                            AlternateText="Delete"  />
                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>

                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#ADD8E6" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#ADD8E6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />

</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the header at the top i used a script to duplicate the header and put it in it's own container. But I still had issues with the footer being visible. I decided to make a  create button in a new page instead of dealing with the footer. It is much more cleaner for the user inputting data into a form instead of gridview footer. In the same fashion i use the edit record button to open the record in a new page for updating / editing it. I also made the gridview page sort by desc to only see the most recent RMAs, removed the duplicate header script, and used paging. no reason to see all the records, just the most recent.

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            AllowPaging="True"
            PageSize="10"
            AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="RMANumber" 
            CellPadding="1" 
            ForeColor="#333333"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="LightGray" />
            <Columns>               
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="False" ShowEditButton="True" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                    ButtonType="Image" CancelImageUrl="Images/Cancel.png" 
                    EditImageUrl="Images/Edit.png" UpdateImageUrl="Images/Update.png" 
                    ControlStyle-Width="60" ControlStyle-Height="20">
                <ControlStyle Height="20px" Width="60px"></ControlStyle>

                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:CommandField>
                <asp:Boundfield DataField="RMANumber" HeaderText="RMA Number" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RMANumber" > <ItemStyle Width="5%" /> </asp:Boundfield>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DconForm" HeaderText="Dcon Form" SortExpression="DconForm" > <ItemStyle Width="3%" /> </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer" HeaderText="Customer" SortExpression="Customer" > <ItemStyle Width="10%" /> </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemBeingReturned" HeaderText="Item(s) Being Returned" SortExpression="ItemBeingReturned" > <ItemStyle Width="10%" /> </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ReasonForReturn" HeaderText="Reason For Return" SortExpression="ReasonForReturn" > <ItemStyle Width="15%" /> </asp:BoundField> 
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Dia" HeaderText="Dia" SortExpression="Dia" > <ItemStyle Width="7%" /> </asp:BoundField> 
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RMADate" HeaderText="RMA Date" SortExpression="RMADate" > <ItemStyle Width="5%" /> </asp:BoundField> 
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ReturnedDate" HeaderText="Returned Date" SortExpression="ReturnedDate" > <ItemStyle Width="5%" /> </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateShipped" HeaderText="Date Shipped" SortExpression="DateShipped" > <ItemStyle Width="5%" /> </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" > <ItemStyle Width="5%" /> </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PIKEContact" HeaderText="PIKE Contact" SortExpression="PIKEContact" > <ItemStyle Width="7%" /> </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DiamondResults" HeaderText="Diamond Results" SortExpression="DiamondResults" > <ItemStyle Width="5%" /> </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProblemSolutionFound" HeaderText="Problem / Solution Found" SortExpression="ProblemSolutionFound" > <ItemStyle Width="15%" /> </asp:BoundField>
                

           
                
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ShowHeader="true" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/Delete.png" Width="60" Height="20" VerticalAlign="Center"
                        CommandName="Delete"
                        AlternateText="Delete"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>

            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#ADD8E6" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#ADD8E6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />

        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PIKE_Intranet_DBConnectionString %>" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [RMATable] WHERE [RMANumber] = @RMANumber" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [RMATable] ([RMANumber], [DconForm], [Customer], [ItemBeingReturned], [ReasonForReturn], [Dia], [RMADate], [ReturnedDate], [DateShipped], [Status], [PIKEContact], [DiamondResults], [ProblemSolutionFound]) VALUES (@RMANumber, @DconForm, @Customer, @ItemBeingReturned, @ReasonForReturn, @Dia, @RMADate, @ReturnedDate, @DateShipped, @Status, @PIKEContact, @DiamondResults, @ProblemSolutionFound)" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [RMATable] ORDER BY [RMANumber] DESC" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [RMATable] SET [DconForm] = @DconForm, [Customer] = @Customer, [ItemBeingReturned] = @ItemBeingReturned, [ReasonForReturn] = @ReasonForReturn, [Dia] = @Dia, [RMADate] = @RMADate, [ReturnedDate] = @ReturnedDate, [DateShipped] = @DateShipped, [Status] = @Status, [PIKEContact] = @PIKEContact, [DiamondResults] = @DiamondResults, [ProblemSolutionFound] = @ProblemSolutionFound WHERE [RMANumber] = @RMANumber">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="RMANumber" Type="String" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="RMANumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DconForm" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Customer" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ItemBeingReturned" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ReasonForReturn" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Dia" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RMADate" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ReturnedDate" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DateShipped" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PIKEContact" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DiamondResults" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ProblemSolutionFound" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DconForm" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Customer" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ItemBeingReturned" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ReasonForReturn" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Dia" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RMADate" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ReturnedDate" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DateShipped" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PIKEContact" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DiamondResults" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ProblemSolutionFound" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RMANumber" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
```